# Machine Learning dataset with many discrete features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

I am working with a medical data set that contains many variables with discrete outputs. For example: type of anesthesia, infection site, Diabetes y/n. And to deal with this I have just been converting them into multiple columns with ones and zeros and then removing one to make sure there is not a direct correlation between them but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the purpose of the transformation. Converting categories to numerical labels may not make sense if the ordinal representation does not correspond to the logic of the categories. In this case, the "one-hot" encoding approach you have adopted is the best way to go, if (as I surmise from your post) the intention is to use the generated variables as the input to some sort of regression model. You can achieve what you are looking to do using `pandas.get_dummies`.

Comment: And you can opt to drop the first level by passing the argument drop_first=True to get_dummies

Comment: to clarify my answer above, it may not matter whether you one-hot encode or translate labels to numerical values (e.g. if you are using tree-based models like random forest). If you are using traditional regression approaches then the caveat stands, So the answer is, in some sense, 
 contingent on the model you are planning to use.